# Mixing OpenGL with Canvas drawing in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-canvas

We have Android app using hardware acceleration drawing some standard items and widgets. And also I have fancy native drawing using OpenGL. The question is, can I mix it with canvas drawing, in method onDraw for example? Does canvas preserve state or made an assumption that there is no such code?

Why do I want it. I want to have one rendering context for drawing, because two drops FPS to no more than 30.